# How to change button background when button is clicked using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

This is as close as I can get to changing a button background in WPF when I click on the button.

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="#313131" />
</Trigger>
```

But using Property="IsPressed" will change the background color for as long as it is pressed.
I would like it to stay the color after it is pressed.

This is my styling

```
<Style x:Key="Button_No_Light_Gray" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="_Border" Background="Red" Margin="1" BorderBrush="#202020">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="#313131" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="#313131" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have looked at other questions similar to this on Stack overflow but their solutions have not worked for me. The background color of the **_Border** must be changed.

Comment: The easist way is to use EventTrigger of Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf along wth ChangePropertyAction.

Comment: @emoacht I appreciate the comment but I do not understand, could you elaborate plz?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/ChangePropertyAction

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on a different way, by **Click** event.

First, you need to add this into you XAML code, as shown below

```
<Button Content="Content"  Width="70" Height="50" Name="BtnColor" Click="BtnColor_Click"/>
```

Then, in the Code Behind you:

```
private void BtnColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            btn.Background = btn.Background == Brushes.Red ? (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFDDDDDD") : Brushes.Red;
        }
```

Note: This will change the color of the button back and forth, by every click. Hope that is not a problem.

If you don't want that, simply set the value of BrushConverter to the one that you need.
For example if you want it to stay red, just go

ConvertFrom("#FFFF0000") instead of what it was.